# The nearest available Street View Google Maps SDK iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need to get a random Street View, but generating random latitude and longitude is not a good way.

Is there any effective method to generate random Street View or check if generated one is available and find nearest if it is not available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `func panoramaView(view: GMSPanoramaView!, error: NSError!, onMoveNearCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)` method from [GMSPanoramaViewDelegate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_panorama_view_delegate-p.html#a49031dcaac611590dbe8409882db02c6) to check if the panorama view for a certain coordinate is unavailable.

Sample implementation:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: CGRectZero)
        panoView.delegate = self
        self.view = panoView

        panoView.moveNearCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 150.312))
  }
}

extension ViewController: GMSPanoramaViewDelegate {
    func panoramaView(view: GMSPanoramaView!, error: NSError!, onMoveNearCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("\(coordinate.latitude) \(coordinate.longitude) not available")
}
```

link to Gist file: https://gist.github.com/ziyang0621/d340e5ff73f131c32375